# hadoop/hive metastore

Tags: hadoop

where do people place their multi user meta store?  I'm going to use mysql but I don't know were I should stick it.  on the name node or on its own server?

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop can really trash the page buffers on a datanode so you probably will do well to keep mySQL off of any of them.

The recommendation to run Hive outside the cluster is a very good one, if only because you will have serious balance problems if you run it inside the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It can be on any machine really.

We installed hive on a node that is not a cluster member (but is only used for staging data to load into hive)  and setup the metastore mysql instance there.